# In characteristic 2 the splitting field of a cubic has degree 6

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field, cubics, splitting-field, positive-characteristic

I have been working on the following problem, from an old p-set of a Galois theory course I found online:

Let $F = \mathbb{F}_2(t)$, the field of rational functions on $\mathbb{F}_2$, and let $f(x) = x^3 + tx + t$. Prove that $f(x)$ is irreducible over $F$, has nonzero square discriminant, yet its splitting field $L$ has degree $6$ over $F$.

I have been able to prove irreducibility and the discriminant is, with the formula for cubics without quadratic term, $-4t^3-27t^2 = t^2$, a nonzero square.

The first step is adjoin $r$ satisfying $f(r) = 0$ by setting $F(r):= F[r]/(f(r))$, so that now over $F(r)$ $f$ has one root.

$x^3+tx+t = (x+r)(x^2+rx+(r^2+t))$

To show the splitting field has degree $6$, it's enough to show that over $F(r)$ the quadratic $x^2+rx+(r^2+t)$ has no roots. This would make the next root to be adjoined to have a quadratic minimal polynomial and we can use the tower law.

I am stuck here. I don't know how to show the quadratic is irreducible over $F(r)$. Would someone have a hint at this?

Comment: [This question and answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46505/how-to-solve-a-quadratic-equation-in-characteristic-2) seem relevant, though I have to say I don't understand it.

Comment: I don't think the discriminant of a cubic is relevant in characteristic $2$. Define $y=x_1^2x_2+x_2^2x_3+x_3^2x_1$. You should be able to find a quadratic equation over $F$ fulfilled by $y$. The splitting field will have degree $3$ iff this quadratic is soluble over $F$.

Comment: Come to think about it, the discriminant is $[(x_1+x_2)(x_1+x_3)](x_2+x_3)^2$ in characteristic two, so is automatically a square.

Comment: Did you try just plugging in a possible root and working through the mess?

Comment: Keith Conrad has an expository paper where he treats cubics including char 2 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/galoistheory/cubicquarticallchar.pdf)  He defines a quadratic resolvent to distinguish between $A_3$ and $S_3$.  Your cubic is Conrad's Example 2.5  This is the approach suggested by @AnginaSeng